# When overriding pressesBegan, etc., on iOS, how to handle multiple presses?

Tags: ios, keyboard-events, uievent

When overriding [`pressesBegan:withEvent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621134-pressesbegan?language=objc) on iOS to handle hardware keyboard events, it passes in an `NSSet` of `UIPress` objects, and a single `UIEvent` object.

When I have decided which of the presses I wish to handle, do I then call

```
[super pressesBegan:[NSSet setWithObject:press] withEvent:event];
```

for each of the presses received in the set of `UIPress` objects, or do I make only one call to `super`'s `pressesBegan` with an updated set of presses that I've decided not to handle, or am I required to pass the original `presses` set unaltered (and so only be allowed to handle either all or none of them).

I actually haven't seen the case where more than one press appears in the set, so the question may be moot, but the existence of a set there makes me think that it's possible, and I'd like to handle it properly if it happens.